# Bars width are wrong using log scale of x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need log scale x-axis. Here is my code:

```
plt.bar(critical_pressures_reversed, mercury_volume_scaled, bottom = 0, log = True, linewidth=0, align="center",width=.1)
plt.title("Mercury intrusion", fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel("Critical Pressure $P_c \, [kPa]$", fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel("Mercury volume $V_m \, [\mu m^3]$", fontsize=16)
plt.grid(b=True, which='major', color='black', linestyle='-',  linewidth=1)
plt.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='gray', linestyle='-',  linewidth=0.15)
frame = plt.gca()
figure = plt.gcf()
frame.set_xscale('log')
frame.set_axisbelow(True)
figure.set_size_inches(12, 6)
plt.savefig("intrusion_6n_press.png", dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.close()
```

Resulting plot:

[image: Example of bar plot with log x-axis here]

How to force pyplot to draw bars with constant width?

I am using matplotlib (1.4.2)

Comment: It doesn't look like a bar chart is the correct type of chart to be using here. Why are you using a bar chart rather than a scatter plot?

Comment: when you are comparing a volume with pressure, I assume you have several data points which as suggested by @will, need's to be plotted either using scatter or using `plt.plot` function. Unless you need to see the distribution of one of your variables, i.e. either pressure or volume, you don't need `plt.bar` but `plt.histogram`

Comment: @MarcinBurz This might help. [CHECK THIS LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448350/how-to-keep-the-width-of-the-bars-the-same-no-matter-the-number-of-bars-we-compa)

Comment: @MarcinBurz The bar function accepts bar widths in array format. Create an array of widths using the numpy.logspace function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `plt.fill` but the bar width should change based on the log. For instance, for a random dataset, the following lines:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x, y = np.random.randint(1,51,10), np.random.randint(1,51,10)
width = 1e-2
for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.fill([10**(np.log10(x[i])-width), 10**(np.log10(x[i])-width), 10**(np.log10(x[i])+width), 10**(np.log10(x[i])+width)],[0, y[i], y[i], 0], 'r', alpha=0.4)
plt.bar(x,y, bottom = 0, log = True, linewidth=0, align="center",width=.1, alpha=0.4)
```

will produce the figure below. Everything you need to do is to choose a proper `width` parameter.
[image]

Comment: Presented approach is complicated a bit but it works. Thanks!